# groupby datetime year-month only

Tags: python, datetime, pandas-groupby

I need to groupby based on the year & month of the Date column so I have a clearer graph presentation and less sample-size.

```
 
df.groupby(df2['Date'])['¢/kWh'].mean()
```

This has helped me to have less sample size and a better presentation. However I need to further **groupby** based on the month and year.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Include your data sample as text/code. For example, the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()`

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
df.groupby(df2['Date'].astype(str).str[0:7])['¢/kWh'].mean()
```